# Getting spinner values and delaying it

Tags: android, sms, delay

Is there a way that i can get the user's chosen time delay in a spinner and set functions to it so I can delay the message? Ho can i delay the message then? Here's the code for the spinner:

```
// Spinner
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
        if(FirstLoad){
            FirstLoad = false;
            return;                         
        }
          Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You chose " + 
              parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()+ " to delay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
          return;
        }
```

Is it possible that i can delay the sending of the sms?

Comment: First ask the question clearly...

Comment: First, I have a spinner that has 4 values in it, 15, 30, 60 seconds and no delay. So clearly when he chose how long the delay is it'll implement first before the sending of the sms continues(e.g the user chose 15 seconds of delay then he pressed send the delay will implement first after 15seconds the toast indicating that the sms has been sent will pop-up. Is there a way that i can get the values of what the user chose and set methods to it like timer so i can delay the sending of the sms?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Handler.By using the postDelayed you can set the Delay time. Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

```
  final Handler handler = new Handler() {

 @Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
super.handleMessage(msg);        

    Bundle bundle = (Bundle) msg.obj;
String strDelay= bundle.getString("delay");

   // Here you can do what ever you want
}
};



public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {                
   Message message = new Message();
   Bundle bun = new Bundle();
   bun.putString("delay", parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
   message.obj = bun;
   handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, Your_Delay_Time_in_Long);
         }
```

Comment: But how can i get the value of the selected spinner and implement the handler?

Comment: At that time of Item Selection you should send a message to the handler.From the message you can get the Bundle then via that bundle you can pass the values..

Comment: Should i put if-else statements on the handler for other delay times? and the "msg" indicates error on the onItemSelected so i changed it to "message"